# Парсинг стены сообщества VK API

Tags: python

начал изучать парсинг сообщества (записи со стены) с помощью python. при запуске (в режиме отладки) не приходят записи со стены сообщества. Буду благодарен если поможете с советами б в чем может быть причина.

```
import time
import vk

import owner as owner
import requests


token = "тут был токен"
version = 5.131
domain = "kirovmp"
count = 100
offset = 0
all_posts = []
filter = all
items = extend = 1


while offset < 1000:
    response = requests.get("https://dev.vk.com/method/wall.get",
                        params={
                            "access_token": token,
                            "v": version,
                            "count": count,
                            "offset": offset,
                            "filter": filter,
                            "fields": items


                        }
                        )
    data = response.json()["response"]["items"]["text"]
    offset += 100
    all_posts.extend(data)
    time.sleep(0.5)

    print(1)
```

Comment: Лучше не размещать свой токен в открытом доступе.

Comment: Использовал как-то библиотеку `vk_api` для выгрузки всех постов с стены: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/2849e83cf26de5f912064d20427bde07c0d0beff/vk_api__examples/wall_get.py#L26 Но не знаю работает ли сейчас этот метод :)

Comment: Оффтоп. Лучше не называйте переменные именами встроенных функций. Тут, кст, такие функции подсвечены: `filter` и `all`. Встроенные функции: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#built-in-funcs